# Best way to filter arrays based on condtion

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm getting data from an API and I want to filter the array down based on the issue state. The following code works, but is there a nice way to write this?

```
let issuesToUse = this.state.issues;

if(this.state.issueState.status === 'closed'){
  issuesToUse = this.state.issues.filter(issue => {
    return issue.state === 'closed';
  })
} else {
  issuesToUse = this.state.issues.filter(issue => {
    return issue.state === 'open';
  })
}
```

Comment: filter with the property? `issuesToUse = this.state.issues.filter(issue => {
    return issue.state === this.state.issueState.status;
  })`

Comment: `const { issues, issueState } = this.state;` then `let issuesToUse = issues.filter(i => i.state === issueState.status);`

Comment: "nice" is in the eye of the beholder. What are the objective measures that will be used in determining "niceness"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In general: `if (a == 1) b = 1; else if (a == 2) b = 2;` can be replaced with `b = a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
issuesToUse = this.state.issues.filter(issue => issue.state === this.state.issueState.status)
```

Comment: the use of `this` in the arrow function would not have been lost in this context?

Comment: @Mario `this` in that context refers to the outer scope, the React component itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you have other states as well, you need to check the state in advance for filtering.

```
let issuesToUse = this.state.issues;

if (['closed', 'open'].includs(this.state.issueState.status)) {
    issuesToUse = this.state.issues.filter(({ state }) => state === this.state.issueState.status)
}
```

Comment: there is a typo in `icluds`

Comment: @Mario, you can edit it :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this example

```
let targetState = this.state.issueState.status;
let issuesToUse = this.state.issues.filter(
  ({ state }) => state === targetState
);
```

See

[Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)